# how to reduce the size of libcrypto.a

Tags: openssl

I am using openssl 0.9.8o

because of the lack of flash size, i have to reduce the size of libcrypto.a, now it remains at 2319KBytes with following configure options

./config no-shared no-zlib no-asm no-threads no-dso no-krb5 no-rc5 no-hw no-md2 no-md4 no-mdc2 no-rc2 no-idea no-camellia no-ec no-ecdsa no-ecdh no-store no-ripemd no-rc4 no-bf no-cast no-ssl no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-tls no-perlasm

i know the .a file is sort of *.o under crypto direction, and the *.o size is bigger under such direction asn1 bn buffer conf

but build failed when add option no-asn1 no-bn no-buffer no-conf,

the request is
1, the basic option of openssl, hope the *.a size is reduced
2, what the relationships of these ciphers

Comment: OpenSSL 0.9.8 is end of life. You should probably switch to 1.0.2. To reduce the size of the ***final executable***, compile the ***library*** with `-ffunction-sections` and `-fdata-sections`. Then, link the ***executable*** with `-Wl,--gc-sections` (Linux) or `-Wl,-dead_strip` (OS X). You should also strip symbols with `strip` utility. Do so on the final executable. If you are only using a few algorithms, then the size of the executable to flash will likely be a KB or two or three. The linker will strip all the dead code.

Comment: hi jww, thanks for your quick comments, if not switch to the neweset version, only focus on the 0.9.8, indeed i used the STRIP symbol in the Makefile, but still the size of the binary file is bigger, so only have to find a way to recude the sizeo of the *.a

Comment: *"but still the size of the binary file is bigger"* - Which file? The library `libcrypto.a` will be big because it has all OpenSSL functions. After linking, dead code removal and stripping, `my_prog` will be small because dead code was removed.

Comment: yes, my libcrypto.a size is big around 2319KB，so i want to use "no cipher" to reduce it, but still find no way.  I downloaded the latest openssl version and compilte it, the size is even bigger

Comment: Usually you don't worry about the size of `libcrypto.a`. Its the size of the final executable you worry about. That's why dead code stripping and symbol stripping is important. They reduce the size of the final executable. Are you building a shared object or a program?

Comment: no-shared, actually, my flash size only 16MB, with binary file with libcrypto.a is almost 3 MB（i used STRIPT in Makefile）, the total rootfs size is always 16MB, the other binary nearly not reducable, so i want to reduce this lib file

Comment: Well, that's unusual. You usually *don't* flash `libcrypto.a` to your device. Typically executables are stored in the ROM, like a program or shared object. You should probably add that to your question. Its an important detail. If you don't mind sharing, why are you flashing an archive like `libcrypto.a`?

Comment: here is something around libcrypto.a in Makefilecp -rf lib/$(PLATFORM_TYPE)/libcrypto.a $(BUILDAPPDIR)/release/libstd/; \
   cp -rf lib/$(PLATFORM_TYPE)/libssl.a  $(BUILDAPPDIR)/release/libstd/; .$(ABC_TASK_BIN) : $(OBJ_FILES) 
  #mv -f $(OBJ_FILES) $(ABC_OBJ_DIR)
  cp -f $(OBJ_FILES) $(ABC_OBJ_DIR)
  $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(ABC_OBJ_DIR)/* -o $@ $(LIBS) $(OPENSSLLIB)
  
  $(STRIP) $@
  @touch $@   the ABC bin file is my executable file with libcrypto.a included. so that is why i have to reduce it's size